# Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository size and repository permissions

Tags: python, azure-devops, automation, repository, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the list of repositories in my azure devops project and list the size of each repository along with the list of access permissions for who has access. I am using python for the script. Here is the below code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicA`your text`uth

# Azure DevOps organization URL
organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/your_organization"

# Personal Access Token (PAT) with appropriate permissions
personal_access_token = "your_personal_access_token"

# Project name
project_name = "your_project_name"

# Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repositories
repo_api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.1"

# Headers for API request
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Basic {personal_access_token}"
}

# Make the API request to get the list of repositories
response = requests.get(repo_api_url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    repositories = response.json()["value"]

    # Iterate through repositories
    for repo in repositories:
        repo_name = repo["name"]
        repo_id = repo["id"]

        # Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository size
        size_api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo_id}/itemsizes?api-version=7.1"

        # Make the API request to get the repository size
        size_response = requests.get(size_api_url, headers=headers)

        # Check if the request was successful
        if size_response.status_code == 200:
            repo_size = size_response.json()["repositorySize"]
            print(f"Repository: {repo_name}, Size: {repo_size} bytes")

            # Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository permissions
            access_api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/securitynamespaces/{repo_id}/permissions?api-version=7.1"

            # Make the API request to get repository permissions
            access_response = requests.get(access_api_url, headers=headers)

            # Check if the request was successful
            if access_response.status_code == 200:
                permissions = access_response.json()["value"]
                print("Access:")
                for permission in permissions:
                    user_name = permission.get("principalName", "Unknown User")
                    permission_name = permission.get("permission", "Unknown Permission")
                    print(f"  User: {user_name}, Permission: {permission_name}")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to retrieve access for repository {repo_name}. Status code: {access_response.status_code}")
                print(access_response.text)
        else:
            print(f"Failed to retrieve size for repository {repo_name}. Status code: {size_response.status_code}")
            print(size_response.text)
else:
    # Print an error message if the request was not successful
    print(f"Failed to retrieve repositories. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
```

The API used above for " Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository size" and "Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository permissions" dont seem to work, i get a 404 error for SizeResponse. Is there any other way to fetch this data or is the API correct ? My PAT has full access in ADO. I am able to fetch the repo list for my project. Only the Size API doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

I double checked the PAT access and gave it full access. There is content in the repositories , so the repos are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

> The API used above for " Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository
> size" and "Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repository permissions"
> don't seem to work.

According to [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and [Security Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security-namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP): the two APIs `_apis/git/repositories/{repo_id}/itemsizes` and `_apis/securitynamespaces/{repo_id}/permissions`  you are using do not exist. So you can't use it like this.

The following is a python script that uses the APIs ([Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) and [Permissions Report - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions-report/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)) to complete your needs. It will download permission reports to the location of the python script.

```
import requests 
import base64
import json
import time


# Personal Access Token (PAT) with appropriate permissions
personal_access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+personal_access_token, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

# Azure DevOps organization URL
organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/orgname"

# Project name
project_name = "projectname"

# Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for repositories
repo_api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project_name}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.2-preview.1"


#retry times
retry_times = 3
current_try = 0

# Headers for API request
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

# Make the API request to get the list of repositories
list_repo_response = requests.get(repo_api_url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if list_repo_response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the JSON response
    repositories = list_repo_response.json()["value"]

    # Iterate through repositories
    for repo in repositories:
        repo_name = repo["name"]
        repo_id = repo["id"]
        repo_size = repo["size"]
        print(f"Repository: {repo_name}, Id: {repo_id} Size: {repo_size} bytes")
        # Azure DevOps REST API endpoint for Permissions Report - Create
        permission_report_url = f"{organization_url}/_apis/permissionsreport?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

        body = json.dumps({
          "descriptors": [],
          "reportName": f"Permission report for repository {repo_name}",
          "resources": [
            {
              "resourceId": f"{repo_id}",
              "resourceType": "repo"
            }
          ]
        })

        # Make the API request  Permissions Report - Create
        permission_report_create_response = requests.request("POST", permission_report_url, headers=headers, data=body)

        # Check if the request was successful
        if permission_report_create_response.status_code == 202:
            current_try = 0
            PermissionReportDownloadLink=permission_report_create_response.json()["_downloadLink"] 
            DownloadLink=PermissionReportDownloadLink["href"]

           # dowmload the Permissions Report
            while current_try < retry_times:
                # delay 30s before download the Permissions Report
                print(f"Delay 30s before download the Permissions Report for repository {repo_name}.json")
                time.sleep(30)

                permission_report_download_response = requests.get(DownloadLink, headers=headers)
                downloaded_file = f"permission report for repository {repo_name}.json"

                if permission_report_download_response.status_code == 200:
                    with open(f'{downloaded_file}', 'wb') as file:
                        # Write the contents of the response to the file
                        file.write(permission_report_download_response.content)
                    print(f"permission report for repository {repo_name}.json is downloaded")
                    break
                else:
                    current_try += 1
                    print(f"Current_try {current_try}: Failed to download Permissions Report for repository {repo_name}. Status code: {permission_report_download_response.status_code}")
                    print(permission_report_download_response.text)
                    
            else:
                print(f"Download {repo_name}.json failed, maximum number {retry_times} of retries reached, DownloadLink is {DownloadLink} ")
        else:

            print(f"Failed to Permissions Report - Create  for repository {repo_name}. Status code: {permission_report_create_response.status_code}")
            print(permission_report_create_response.text)
else:
    # Print an error message if the request was not successful
    print(f"Failed to retrieve repositories. Status code: {list_repo_response.status_code}")
    print(list_repo_response.text)
```

Test result:

[image]

[image]

By the way, as you can see in the result, [Rate and usage limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops) may be triggered if a large number of requests occur in a short period of time.

Comment: So when i run the above code , the Download permissions report is getting trigerred on the ADO console , and i am getting an email notification after few seconds which will have the link to download the permissions report. So there is time lag here between the trigger and email notification . How are you able to download the json report in the script folder?

Comment: i get the below error :i am getting the below error : Failed to download Permissions Report for repository AdoAutomation-ServiceNow. Status code: 404
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Permissions report is not available for download.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PermissionsReport.PermissionsReportDownloadNotAvailableException,

Comment: Hi @Automation, the permission report generation may take some time. Sometimes this takes a little longer. In order to avoid download failure before the report is generated, we can add delay time to the script and retry several times if the download fails. I have updated the answer with time delay and retry.